# $\int_{0}^{1/\pi} \left(px^{p-1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - x^{p-2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) dx $, $p$ values for proper/improper int.?

Tags: real-analysis

> Find all the values of $p$ for which the integral $$\int_{0}^{\frac1{\pi}} \left(px^{p-1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - x^{p-2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) dx $$ exist
>   (i) as proper integrals
>   (ii) as improper integrals
>   (iii) evaluate the integrals for the values of p for which they converge

$$\int_{0}^{\frac1{\pi}} \left(px^{p-1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - x^{p-2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) dx $$
$$ = \left[ x^p \sin (\frac{1}{x}) \right]_0^{1/\pi} = \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \left[x^p \sin (\frac{1}{x})\right]_t^{1/\pi} = \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0^+} [- (t^p) sin(1/t)]$$

When $t \rightarrow 0^+$, we have $\sin \frac{1}{t}$ oscillating between $-1$ and $1$.

3 cases can be identified: $p>0, p=0, p<0$
[Given that proper integral is defined as an integral respecting Riemann Integral definition, if not, the integral is improper

.

$\forall p>0$, $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0^+} t^p sin(1/t) = 0$. Eventhough $f(0)$ cannot be defined, $f$ is bounded on the closed interval $[0, 1/\pi]$ , its limit exists and finite it is therefore considered to be a proper integral. (paraphrasing the argumentation of an online book "Trench"). It is convergent.

.

If $p=0$, the integral oscillates from -1 to 1. therefore divergent as the limit doesnt exist. It is then an improper integral.

.

$\forall p<0$, $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0^+} t^p = - \infty$ it is therefore divergent.

Am i going in the right direction? I am unsure about my definition regarding proper and improper. Are my definitions and argumentation on this correct? thx for your input.

Comment: I suppose that you noticed that $$\int \left(px^{p-1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - x^{p-2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\, dx=x^p \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ If $p$ is an integer, consider separtely odd and even values of it. This could help (I hope).

Comment: For every real $p$, actually, since we are restricted to $x>0$. :-)

Comment: thx for your input. I did a re-edit. I did not see the need of considering even and odd. Is my re-edit incorrect?